# Garbage collector in Android is running, but nothing is shown as being allocated in ddms' allocation tracker

Tags: android, enums, garbage-collection, ddms

In my application, I'm careful not to make heap allocations in the main render loop, to prevent the garbage collector from having to do its thing.

After making a series of changes to my application, I suddenly see the garbage collector getting invoked every second or two, and it is freeing up around 400k of memory per invocation.

I look back at the changes that I made, and I don't have any explicit allocations happening on the render thread. So I run ddms and use the "Allocation Tracker" tool, but there are no allocations happening, other than the normal ones that are related to running ddms. And certainly not enough allocations shown for the 400k bytes that are apparently being garbage collected every second or so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I had already found the solution but am posting the question+answer for other's benefit)

As it turns out, I was able to track the problem down to calling the .values() method of a enum class, which allocates a new array on every call. But for some reason, those allocations don't show up in ddms's allocation tracker, so it makes it rather difficult to track down.

Luckily, I was able to use git bisect to find the specific change that introduced the issue, and then tracked it down to the exact problem in that change.

Edit:
After some additional testing, it seems that cloning an array in general doesn't show up in the allocation tracker.

Additional Info:
This seems to be an issue in Honeycomb and below, when cloning an object. It will be fixed in ICS. (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19831)

Comment: You should avoid using enums if possible ... most of the time it's possible to create static int fields, and I prefere using standard classes for anything more advanced. Enums seem to be pretty expensive in Java

Comment: They're actually not that bad, it just depends on how you use them. If you find that they are causing a specific performance problem in your application, by all means optimize things and use static ints. But in most cases, there likely won't be any significant/noticeable performance impact when using enums.

Comment: Agree, but using 
    public static final int SOMETHING = 1;
is definitely better than using
    public enum VALUES { SOMETHING };

enums were added to the language quite late if I am not mistaken and are supposed to be too expensive overall

Comment: It depends on how you define "better". If you are using a simple enum like that, I agree that you don't get any advantage by using an enum. However, you can add additional fields to an enum, and it becomes a useful abstraction.

Comment: @JesusFreke: When you say that "cloning an array in general doesn't show up in the allocation tracker", what specific code is being used? This sounds like a tools bug, so I was hoping to reproduce your results.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I wrote up a quick hello-world style app, in which it spawns a thread in onCreate that does an infinite loop where it just clones an array. Obviously, the garbage collector goes crazy, but when you look at the allocations happening in the allocation tracker, the arrays don't show up

Comment: @JesusFreke: What, **exactly**, do you mean by "clone an array"? `System.arraycopy()`? A `for` loop? `Arrays.copyOf()`? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare: oh, sorry. int blah[] = new int[10]; while(true) {blah.clone();}

Comment: @JesusFreke: I can reproduce your problem. I have reported it [on the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19831). I'm not sure if this is a tooling problem or a limitation of Dalvik VM's reporting capability.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide info about the kind of garbage colletor.
Bitmap allocation, meaning the actual bitmap pixels(not bitmap information which is very small) is allocated into the heap, **BUT** not visible to any allocation tracker tool for android version below 3.0 (Honeycomp). So if you are loading bitmap information GC extrernal allocation will be called.

Comment: Yeah, sounds similar to what I was seeing. In my case it was due to an array clone that was happening when I called <enum>.values(). I'll have to try my test case on my honeycomb tablet and see if the problem is fixed there

Comment: Nope, cloning an array still doesn't show up in the allocation tracker on Honeycomb (3.0)