# Which object(s) is causing GC_EXPLICIT?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, dalvik

For some reason my app is triggering a `GC_EXPLICIT` way too much and because of that probably slowing it down.

Is there any way to find out which objects are causing this?

I've tried using DDMS to find out if there is a problem with allocations but that looks okay.

Also, even with that amount of GC calls, it is still clogging my external heap in time :( 
so its not helping alot either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the `values()` method of an enum by chance? Or the .clone() method of an array()?  (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296781/garbage-collector-in-android-is-running-but-nothing-is-shown-as-being-allocated))

Comment: I am cloning object with array's in it. 
But for that i'm creating new Arraylists and filling them with cloned objects.  (instead of cloning the list itself).

I've lost most of the Explicit calls by now.  
But my heap memory still is clogging. 
Came across a new issue tho, and i'd better make a new question for that.   Saving Canvas state ; I'm using a foreach loop to canvas.drawText(text,x,y,Paint)  It would be better if i could save the canvas after that so that i would have to redo the foreach everytime right ? 
just cant figure it out yet... canvas stays empty on the second run.

Comment: Right, that would be better off as a different question :)