# Diagnosing garbage collection (or other kind of interruption)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an animated game which is generally achieving 25-30 frames per second, though occasionally freezes for a quarter of a second here and there. From looking at assorted posts I guess it is probably doing some garbage collection.

I am using eclipse and am armed with DDMS and the internal profiler - which I haven't fully got to grips with yet. But as far as I can tell there seem to be very few and infrequent memory allocations going on, and the ones there are seem very small. Also when looking at the list of functions and what percentage of the time they are taking, I can not see anything strange. Mind you I don't quite know what to looking for - is there a function called DoingGarbageCollectionNow() or similar that I should see on the list? I can't find anything like it.

**EDIT:** The little freezes only appear obvious on my Samsung Galaxy Y (Android 2.3.5). On my Google Nexus S (Android 2.3.3), the frame rate is 25 or more throughout.

**EDIT:** Could the delays even be caused by another app (or OS procedure) running in the background - and if so, how could I tell?

Comment: No. Unfortunately in java world you can't really force to do garbage collection now. It is runtime (JVM) responsibility.

Comment: I didn't mean is there a function I can call - I meant is there a function I may see on the profiler report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't wrote on android specifically, but generally you want to examine gc in logging to see it's behavior and timing.

See this article for android specific gc logging info. http://www.infectentertainment.com/2010/05/28/android-garbage-collection/

Platform agnostic solution may be to look at a parallel gc or other gc types if possible on the platform.
"The concurrent collector introduced in Gingerbread helps[...]" Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Better solution still is to avoid instantiation if at all possible by examining creation of objects in loops and eliminating them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my app, and I finally tracked it down to using the .clone() method on an array. There's a bug in android/ddms supposedly where allocations created by clone method don't show up in the allocation tracker. So you'll see frequent garbage collection even though you don't see any allocations (very frustrating!)

See [Garbage collector in Android is running, but nothing is shown as being allocated in ddms' allocation tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296781/garbage-collector-in-android-is-running-but-nothing-is-shown-as-being-allocated) for more.